# Reading Explorer.exe's Thunk Data

Tags: 64-bit, hook, windows-explorer, thunk

I'm trying to do a little IAT hooking in explorer.exe. Specs: Windows 7 x64, Visual C++. I've made it to a point where I am capable of reading thunk data from any executable of my choosing except for C:\Windows\Explorer.exe. When I run my program against that I receive an access violation in reading memory from that executable. However, when I run this against C:\Windows\system32\Explorer.exe and C:\Windows\sysWOW64\Explorer.exe I don't have any problems. Why is this? Is C:\Windows\Explorer.exe some sort of symbolic link to one of the other explorer.exe's? What could be keeping me from reading this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Windows 7 x64 system `C:\windows\explorer.exe` is a 64-bit binary, `PE32+` format, whereas `c:\windows\syswow64\explorer.exe` is a 32-bit binary, `PE32` format.  Is your application designed to read both `PE32` and `PE32+` formats?

And when opening `C:\Windows\System32\Explorer.exe` from a 32-bit process that is a redirect to the `c:\windows\syswow64\explorer.exe` copy.  From a 64-bit process `c:\windows\system32\explorer.exe` doesn't exist.

Comment: Firstly, awesome info. My process does not take into account PE32+ formatting. At a quick glance, it appears to be easy enough to change all of the IMAGE_HEADER structs to the 64 bit format. Are you implying that I need to compile my program for x64 in order to read C:\windows\explorer.exe or just make changes to support the PE32+ formatting?

Comment: It depends on what your program is doing.  If you just want to parse PE32+ format a 32-bit binary will be fine.  However you say IAT Hooking, this implies injecting your own code into a process.  In which case the architecture of the code you inject needs to match the architecture of the process that is running.  So 32-bit code for a 32-bit process and 64-bit code for a 64-bit process.